# Unable to drop constraint in SQL server 2005, "Could not drop constraint. See previous errors"

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints, alter-table

I'm trying to drop a constraint on a DB table, something like:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable drop CONSTRAINT FK_MyTable_AnotherTable
```

But the execution just runs and runs. If I stop it I see:

```
Msg 3727, Level 16, State 0, Line 2
Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.
```

Web search throws up various pages but note that the constraint is properly named and I am trying to remove it using the correct name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a way to sort this, although I don't understand why it was necessary.

Have been able to drop the constraint by disabling it first:

```
ALTER MyTable NOCHECK CONSTRAINT FK_MyTable_AnotherTable
```

The drop then completes fine

Would still welcome any comments on the reason why this is necessary

Comment: I want to remove a column that is neither Primary nor Foreign key, I was getting the same error, i tried your  solution but it did't work. any ideas ?

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same issue on **SQL Server 2008 R2**, I solved my problem with below line hopefully it will work for someone else as well :)

```
    Alter Table [Table Name]
    DROP Column [Column Name]
```

Comment: may i know the reason for giving my ans -1 ? I will be happy if you correct me.

Comment: i hope you got already the answer for your why. I don't think that the thread owner wanna drop any column, he just want drop the foreign key (maybe to change the column definition)

Answer (score 2):

Verify that you've not already dropped the constraint, like:

```
SELECT OBJECT_ID('FK_MyTable_AnotherTable')
```

If this returns `null`, your constraint no longer exists.  That would explain the error message.

Comment: No the constraint has not already been removed, I have tried your method as well as others and it definitely still exists. It will also stop me dropping the associated column

Comment: @DannykPowell: What does `object_id('FK_MyTable_AnotherTable','F')` display?

Comment: See my answer, have sorted by disabling constraint first- thanks for your answer @Andomar

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem.

The reason was that I made a mistake in my cursor statement, which was iterating some constraint I was to drop.
So this error occurred when the constraint was actually **removed in the same transaction**. Then I did a rollback and checked if it existed: it did (of course, after rollback!).

Check if it really exists at the moment of dropping.