# Update optional FK to Required with Automatic Migrations

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have a table which has an optional FK to another table and want to change that FK to a required relationship.

I have Automatic Migrations enabled and enabled destructive changes for this update. All entities in the database also have this key populated.

I changed this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>().HasOptional(b => b.AuthorSecurable).WithMany().Map(b => b.MapKey("AuthorSecurableId"));
```

to:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>().HasRequired(b => b.AuthorSecurable).WithMany().Map(b => b.MapKey("AuthorSecurableId"));
```

and got the following error:

> 'FK_dbo.Blogs_dbo.Securables_AuthorSecurableId' is not a constraint.
>   Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.

There are no previous errors I could see (no inner exception ect.)

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592977/unable-to-drop-constraint-in-sql-server-2005-could-not-drop-constraint-see-pre) says you can get around this error with the following:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Blogs] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Blogs_dbo.Securables_AuthorSecurable_Id]
```

so i did:

```
public override void Up()
{
    Sql("ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Blogs] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Blogs_dbo.Securables_AuthorSecurable_Id]");
    DropForeignKey("dbo.Blogs", "AuthorSecurableId", "dbo.Securables");
    DropIndex("dbo.Blogs", new[] { "AuthorSecurableId" });
    AlterColumn("dbo.Blogs", "AuthorSecurableId", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
    AddForeignKey("dbo.Blogs", "AuthorSecurableId", "dbo.Securables", "Id", cascadeDelete: true);
    CreateIndex("dbo.Blogs", "AuthorSecurableId");
}
```

But still got the same error

**EDIT:**

the full code is avaliable [here](https://github.com/lukemcgregor/StaticVoid.Blog/blob/master/Blog/Data/BlogContext.cs) and a minimal models are below:

```
public class Blog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Securable AuthorSecurable { get; set; }
}

public class Securable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Luke could you post the full (minimal) relevant model as it's something specific

Comment: @NSGaga I've posted minimal models as requested, all of the code is also available on github (see link in post)

Comment: Have you scripted actions required directly in SQL server Management studio.  Ie Confirmed what alter statements are required and in what sequence?

Comment: @soadyp no I was hoping to be able to do this with EF migrations. Im confident I could make this change with raw SQL but that's a last resort

Comment: any news Luke. Any luck with this ?

Comment: @soadyp It just started working the next day without any kind of additional SQL. I think perhaps it was some hanging transaction on the database that a reboot dropped. In any case it resolved itself.

Comment: Oh.. wow..  Good to know. Im glad it wasnt an EF bug :-)